# Multi-label text classification with scikit-learn, which classifiers to use?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have done text classification using scikit-learn Python library importing these classifiers:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestCentroid
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

The input text was in the form:

```
('some text 1', 'class1')
('some text 2', 'class2')
('some text 3', 'class3')
...
```

And everything was ok. But what I want to know is if I have multi-labeled text like:

```
('some text 1', 'class1', 'class3')
('some text 2', 'class2', 'class1')
('some text 3', 'class3')
...
```

if that is possible to use these classifiers, or should I use some other classifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classifiers able to do Multi-class or Multi-Label are referred on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Based on it, only 2 of your models can be used directly as multi-label:

- RandomForestClassifier
- KNeighborsClassifier

After what I've done (in an exercice), is to use a OneVsAll with another compatible classifier then extract the top N or all labels above X% (the more labels you have, the lower will be the threshold as the sum is equal to 1). It's not the cleanest thing you can do but it works (I compared it with multi-label classifier results and it was pretty close or identical)

I hope it helps,
Nicolas

Comment: Thank you for your very concise answer, I will try the method you suggest. Just a question: multiclass-multioutput is the only one that can be used for multi-labeled classification? Since others seem to be used for multi-class but don't have multi-label output, does this fact makes the difference

Comment: Multiclass-Multioutput is different to simple multilabel. If you want to classify for example a meal, with multilabel, you gonna have maybe (salty : Yes/No, Good : Yes/No, Warm : Yes/No). With a Multiclass-Multioutput you may have (taste : sweet/salty/acid, Good: Tastefull/correct/bad/horrible, ...). If you label are binary, you can use either Support multilabel or Support multiclass-multioutput. You you can have several output, it's gonna be Support multiclass-multioutput only. But you can everytime convert a multioutput to a multilabel by doing a One Hot Encoder on all solutions